# Lights off puzzle Optimal solution

Tags: java, swing, optimization

Lights Off is a puzzle game consisting of an n x n grid of lights. At the beginning of the game, some of the lights are switched on. When a light is pressed, this light and the four adjacent lights are toggled, i. e., they are switched on if they were off, and switched off otherwise. The purpose of the game is to switch all the lights off.

Input:

```
000
110
010
```

Output should be

```
000
000
000
```

by selecting cell 00, 10, 11, 21 & 22.

I made following program, it is working fine, I just want to know if there is any more optimal way to resolve it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class lightOff extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  public static final int W = 400;
  public static final int H = 200;
  JButton[][] lights = new JButton[3][3];
  int COLS = 3, ROWS = 3;
  public lightOff()
  {
      super("Light Off"); 
      setSize(W,H);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  String[][] input = {{"0","0","0"},{"1","1","0"},{"0","1","0"}};
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
          //input=kb.next();
          lights[i][j] = new JButton();
          lights[i][j].addActionListener(this);
          lights[i][j].setText(input[i][j]);
          add(lights[i][j]);

      }
  }

  }
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       lightOff obj1 = new lightOff();
       obj1.setVisible(true);
    }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       JButton action = (JButton)e.getSource();
       if(action==lights[0][0])
        {
       if("0".equals(lights[0][0].getText()))
          lights[0][0].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[0][0].setText("0");
         // edgeToggle(0,0,action);
       forward(0,0);
       down(0,0);

      }

      else if(action==lights[0][1])
      {
        if(lights[0][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[0][2].setText("1");
        else 
          lights[0][2].setText("0");

        backward(0,1);
        forward(0,1);
        down(0,1);
   }

   else if(action==lights[0][2])
   {
       if(lights[0][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[0][2].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[0][2].setText("0");
         // edgeToggle(0,2,action);
       backward(0,2);
       down(0,2);
   }

   else if(action==lights[1][0])
   {
     if(lights[1][0].getText()=="0")
          lights[1][0].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[1][0].setText("0");

     up(1,0);
     down(1,0);
     forward(1,0);
   }

   else if(action==lights[1][1])
   {
     if(lights[1][1].getText()=="0")
          lights[1][1].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[1][1].setText("0");

     up(1,1);
     down(1,1);
     backward(1,1);
     forward(1,1);
   }


   else if(action==lights[1][2])
   {
     if(lights[1][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[1][2].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[1][2].setText("0");

     up(1,2);
     down(1,2);
     backward(1,2);
   }



   else if(action==lights[2][0])
   {
       if(lights[2][0].getText()=="0")
          lights[2][0].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[2][0].setText("0");
        //  edgeToggle(2,0,action);
       up(2,0);
       forward(2,0);

   }

   else if(action==lights[2][1])
   {
     if(lights[2][1].getText()=="0")
          lights[2][1].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[2][1].setText("0");

     up(2,1);
     backward(2,1);
     forward(2,1);
   }


   else if(action==lights[2][2])
   {
       if(lights[2][2].getText()=="0")
          lights[2][2].setText("1");
       else 
          lights[2][2].setText("0");
   //       edgeToggle(2,2,action);
       up(2,2);
       backward(2,2);
   }
   }



   public void forward(int a, int b)
   {
      if("0".equals(lights[a][b+1].getText()))
       lights[a][b+1].setText("1");
      else
       lights[a][b+1].setText("0");
   }

  public void backward(int a, int b)
   {
   if("0".equals(lights[a][b-1].getText()))
       lights[a][b-1].setText("1");
   else
       lights[a][b-1].setText("0");
   }

   public void up(int a, int b)
   {
   if("0".equals(lights[a-1][b].getText()))
       lights[a-1][b].setText("1");
   else
       lights[a-1][b].setText("0");
    }

   public void down(int a, int b)
   {
   if("0".equals(lights[a+1][b].getText()))
       lights[a+1][b].setText("1");
   else
       lights[a+1][b].setText("0");
   }


   }
```

Guys please I need your feedback on this, as Java is new to me so I need to know more optimal way of resolving this problem.

Comment: This would be a case for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow. But you should format your code properly before posting there.

Comment: Also identify the [algorithm(s)](https://www.google.com/?q=lights%20off%20puzzle%20algorithm) you've implements/examined.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by not using arrays, unless you have to.  I would create a class for each button or light that includes the button itself, the actual value (on/off) and probably location in the grid.  Then I would use a HashMap or EnumMap as the lights.

```
public class Light {
boolean value= false;    
JButton button = new JButton();
int xloc = 0;
int yloc = 0;
}
```

...
Goes in place of "lights":

```
HashMap<String, Light> lights = new ...; //Look it up
lights.put("A1",new Light());
```

This is to get you started.  You'll want more, but I wanted to leave you with something to work with.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten `actionPerformed()` by calculating the row and column index from the button index (0..8) and replacing `forward()`, `backward()`, `up()` and `down()` by `toggle()` with appropriate arguments (checked in the function), reducing the nine cases to one.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      JButton action = (JButton)e.getSource();
      int buttin = action.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleIndexInParent();
      int row = buttin/COLS;
      int col = buttin%COLS;
      toggle(row,   col  );
      toggle(row-1, col  );   // up
      toggle(row+1, col  );   // down
      toggle(row,   col-1);   // backward
      toggle(row,   col+1);   // forward
   }

      void toggle(int row, int col)
      {
         if (0 <= row && row < ROWS && 0 <= col && col < COLS)
            if (lights[row][col].getText() == "0")
                lights[row][col].setText("1");
            else 
                lights[row][col].setText("0");
      }
```